# Converting Map Files to KML Overlay

Tags: arcobjects, kml, .net, sdk

Had a quick look around and didn't quite see what I've been looking for.

I've got a .Net Web Application that is going to accept different map files and I want to convert everything over to KML so all of the different maps can be displayed in the same way. We are going to be accepting KML/KMZ overlays, Geospatial PDFs and other map types that include topology and other map overlays. Once they are converted they will be added to their 'MyMaps' so they can choose which overlays they want to have over top of Google Maps.

```
<asp:Content ID="content7" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphAfter">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h2>My Maps:</h2>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMapSelect_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Add Maps:</h3>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input id="txtMapLocation" type="file" runat="server" name="yourinputname" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddMap" Text="Add Map" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddMap_Click" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

What software from ArcGIS is going to be needed to perform this?

I already have the SDK for .Net and have a request for ArcGIS Desktop. Just curious what objects are going to be needed from which packages to accomplish this task.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Loading maps already uploaded into DropDownlist to Select
}
protected void btnAddMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Upload map then convert to KML format, store on server, create entry for map location in DB
}
protected void ddlMapSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //When map is selected, find overlay and add it to the google map created by master template
}
```

Code is still pretty rough right now, it's early on in development. But I hope it gives a good enough idea of what I need to get done.